# Add content in TitlePane

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to add several TreeViews into TitlePana.

```
private static TitledPane pane = new TitledPane("Connections", null);


public static void initTree(String name)
    {
        pane.setContent(tree(name));
    }

pane.setContent(<node>);
```

But when I add TreeView the new node always replaces the old one. Is this a design problem. Any idea is this a code problem?

Answer (score 6):

Set the content of the titled pane to some layout pane, and then add the tree views to the layout pane.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TreesInATitledPane extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane();
        titledPane.setText("Trees");

        final VBox forest = new VBox(5);

        final int NUM_TREES = 4 ;
        for (int i=1; i<= NUM_TREES; i++) {
            forest.getChildren().add(createRandomTree("Tree "+i));
        }

        titledPane.setContent(forest);

        final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(titledPane);
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 600);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Can't see the forest for the trees");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public TreeView<String> createRandomTree(String prefix) {
        final Random rng = new Random();
        List<TreeItem<String>> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>(prefix + " Root");
        root.setExpanded(true);
        nodes.add(root);
        for (int i=1 ; i < 15; i++) {
            final TreeItem<String> treeItem = new TreeItem<>(prefix + " Item "+i);
            treeItem.setExpanded(true);
            nodes.get(rng.nextInt(i)).getChildren().add(treeItem);              
            nodes.add(treeItem);
        }
        TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<>(root);
        return tree ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested to use VBox but it turns out that the TreeView components are not placed below each other. They are placed equally on the TitledPane which is not good. Is there another solution? For example several tree root nodes into one TreeView?

Comment: I don't know what "placed equally on the TitledPane" means. I tried this and it works just fine.